# sdl: unlock mouse in fullscreen mode and make it useable on another monitor

Tags: c++, sdl

Is it possible to unlock the mouse in fullscreen mode so that you can use it on a another monitor? I read trough the SDL documentation, but I couldn't find anything related to my problem.

edit: I posted the same question on http://gamedev.stackexchange some days ago, but nobody answered it, hence I crossposted to the main site
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49948/sdl-unlock-mouse-in-fullscreen-mode-and-make-it-useable-on-another-monitor

edit2: I've already tried windowed fullscreen mode with the help of an external program, but performance was a lot worse than in fullscreen mode

Comment: not sure about SDL but idea is to run your application in "windowed fullscreen" mode. World of Warcraft has it, for example, you can WinSpy window flags.

Comment: I tried that by using an external program, but performance was a lot worse than in fullscreen mode

Comment: SDL 1.2 or 1.3/2.0?  OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way of doing it.

You could fake it by using SDL_SetVideoMode().
Set it to the exact size of the desktop and use the SDL_NOFRAME flag.
Desktop size can be acquired with

```
const SDL_VideoInfo* videoInfo = SDL_GetVideoInfo();    //get desktop size
desktopWidth = videoInfo->current_w;
desktopHeight = videoInfo->current_h;
```

and this hack can work on any resolution.

Comment: as stated in the comments, I already tried that before. Maybe I should have made that clear in the OP

Comment: @kayyy SDL will work the same speed with or without SDL_FULLSCREEN flag. You don't need an external program to do this.(sry didn't see your comments)

Comment: I read somewhere that playing windowed decreases your performance by ~15%, but maybe I'll just give it another try

Comment: @kayyy I just tested it-> no difference.